# Backpack Laravel on cPanel: Invalid backend configuration. Readable volumes not available

Tags: laravel, cpanel, laravel-backpack, elfinder

I upload my Laravel project to cPanel along with Backpack, but I have an issue with the Invalid backend configuration. Readable volumes not available.

My folder is located at public folder [uploads]

[image]

Any idea on how to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Setting this up on different hosting providers can be a pain sometimes. Shared hosting especially. I don't know exactly why YOU are getting this THAT PARTICULAR HOST, I suspect on localhost it worked fine for you. But what I recommend is to look for solutions inside https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder - that's the repo that provides the actual functionality behind this Backpack feature.